# Minecraft crashes after launching with buildcraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-buildcraft

I just installed Minecraft 1.6.2 and then installed forge. The game launches  Forge and the Timber mod but when I attempted to add the Buildcraft mod, the game just crashes. The Mojang screen appears and then the game closes. I don't know what is happening. There isn't and error report or anything, the game just closes.

Comment: Is this mod compatible with the latest version of Minecraft?

Comment: yesa i downloaded it for 1.6.2

Comment: Search for files named "hs_err_pid(numbers).log" Either where the minecraft launcher(or whatever you launched the game with) is located or the .minecraft folder and show us Both of them(if applicable).

Comment: Where did you download this mod?

Comment: Modded minecraft crashing is categorically off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You've been tricked

The latest [BuildCraft (version 3.7.2) from the official download site](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/buildcraft/) is for Minecraft 1.5.2. It will not work for Minecraft 1.6.2.

Either you downloaded it from a scam/malware site that lied about being compatible with 1.6.2 (scam mod sites are very common, since it's easy to prey on people hoping for mods compatible with the latest Minecraft version), or someone well-meaning simply didn't understand compatibility and was wrong when they told you it would work with 1.6.2.

There is no fix. You'll have to either downgrade to Minecraft 1.5.2 and use that to play BuildCraft, or wait for BuildCraft to update to Minecraft 1.6.x.

### Always download mods from reputable sources you trust!

Never find mods by Googling. Either find the mod on the author's site or from [Minecraftforums.net pinned mod list thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/51-minecraft-mods/). Anywhere else is either illegally redistributing the real mod or is offering a fake mod that might be malware.

Even if it's the real mod, they often provide inaccurate or misleading compatibility information to boost downloads and their advertising income, leaving you with a mod that simply doesn't work while they get paid for your misfortune.